# How to remove stronger line in the middle of graph for android MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, android-emulator, mpandroidchart

My MPAndroidChart displays a stronger line to represent the middle of the graph. How do I avoid that please?

[image]

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
private fun addChart(totals: Totals) {

    chart1.apply {
        isDragEnabled = true
        isScaleXEnabled = false
        isScaleYEnabled = true
        axisRight.isEnabled = false
        axisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false)
        xAxis.isEnabled = false
        legend.isEnabled = false
        description.text = ""
        setTouchEnabled(false)
    }

    val y: YAxis = chart1.axisLeft
    y.axisMaximum = 800f
    y.axisMinimum = 0f
    y.labelCount = 5

    val yValues = ArrayList<Entry>()

    for ((index, i) in totals.features!!.withIndex()) {

        yValues.add(Entry(index.toFloat(), i.attributes?.confirmedCovidCases!!.toFloat()))

    }

    val set1 = LineDataSet(yValues, "Data set 1")
    set1.color = resources.getColor(R.color.orange)
    set1.setDrawCircles(false)

    val dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
    dataSets.add(set1)
    val data = LineData(dataSets)

    chart1.data = data
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: please provide some minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Francislainy Has you try the method setDrawGridBackground(false) to hide the grid lines?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to remove the grids but just the stronger line in the middle.

Comment: Try remove limit line from yaxis use removeAllLimitLines()

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I'm afraid that doesn't seem to be solution as tried it here and it didn't work.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos is it all the code that handles the chart? can you share your XML layout? I try to recreate your chart using your code and did not have problem https://imgur.com/df5ZJWo

Comment: Hi, yes.   
    ```implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'```

Comment: ```<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/chart1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nationalTotalsLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />```

Comment: The above are the only extra things missing from my question related to the chart.

Comment: Did you try to run it on device? because it might your PC/simulator pixel bleeding

Comment: Hi, yes, great catch! Run now on my device and it worked. If you would like to post this suggestion as an answer I can upvote and accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to recreate your chart but did not have the problem
[image]

Try to run it on device, because it might your PC/simulator pixel bleeding